# Is it possible to call a non-final function in constructor?

Tags: android, kotlin, inheritance, mvvm, viewmodel

I'm developing a huge section of my Android app in Jetpack Compose with the MVVM pattern.

I have a ViewModel father that is extended by all the other ViewModels. There, I have defined an open function which contains the initialization logic of each ViewModel that I need to call every time I enter in a new screen and to call again when something went wrong and the user clicks on the "try again" button.

```
abstract class MyFatherViewModel(): ViewModel() {

    open fun myInitMethod() {}

    fun onTryAgainClick() {
        myInitMethod()
    }

}


class MyScreen1ViewModel(): MyFatherViewModel() {

    init {
        myInitMethod()
    }

    override fun myInitMethod() {
        super.myInitMethod()
        // Do something
    }

}


class MyScreen2ViewModel(): MyFatherViewModel() {

    init {
        myInitMethod()
    }

    override fun myInitMethod() {
        super.myInitMethod()
        // Do something
    }

}
```

Is there a way I can call this method in the init function of MyFatherViewModel instead of doing it in all the children ViewModels? If I try to do that, it gives me the "Calling non-final function in constructor" warning and, of course, it doesn't work.

```
abstract class MyFatherViewModel(): ViewModel() {

    open fun myInitMethod() {}

    init {
        myInitMethod()
    }

    fun onTryAgainClick() {
        myInitMethod()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to call a non-final function in constructor?

Technically yes, but you shouldn't. Kotlin is trying to protect you from problems here. If you call an open function from a constructor, it means you are running code from the child class before the parent class is completely initialized, and before the child class even started initializing. If the child implementation of the open function tries to access properties from the child class, unexpected things may happen. For instance, non-nullable properties could yield `null` (because not initialized yet), or primitive values could yield their type's default instead of the default value from their initializer:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    Child()
}

open class Parent {
    
    init {
        initialize()
    }
    
    val id = 42
    
    open fun initialize() = println("parent init")
}

class Child : Parent() {
    
    val name = "Bob"
    
    override fun initialize() = println("initializing $name, parent id=$id")
}
```

This prints the following output:

```
initializing null, parent id=0
```

I guess you can see why this is dangerous.

Maybe you should reconsider what you're trying to do with this try-again feature. Maybe a new view model should be instantiated instead (if try-again is to handle crashes, the state of the current view model may actually be bad enough to want to re-create it from scratch anyway).